# OSGi based example projects

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I searched a lot on internet but I couldn't find enough sample projects based on OSGi. Does anybody know a repository where I can find some OSGi-based sample project.

For example, Oracle Pet Store example project for JavaEE. Similarly, any sample project for OSGi (Equinox or Felix).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two examples part of the Amdatu project:

1. [Amdatu Chat](https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/amdatu-examples-chat)
2. [Amdatu web shop](https://bitbucket.org/amdatu/showcase)

The examples include Mongo, JPA, an Angular based UI, RabbitMQ, REST, Configuration and integration tests.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout what is going on with [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains an SVN repository for an example paint application.  When I was learning OSGi, I just went through the Apache Felix tutorial from the same site, and I found that to be really helpful.

[Felix Application Demonstration](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-application-demonstration.html)